# How can I use regex to match an integer with Haskell?

Tags: regex, haskell

How can I retrieve a `123 :: Integer` value from a string like `123_` using any regex related Haskell library?

```
import Text.Regex.Posix

let (_,_,_,[sectionKey]) = ("123_") =~ ("(\\d+)_" :: String) :: (String, String, String, [Int])
```

I've tried the above (using the https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-posix library) which produces an error of:

```
• No instance for (RegexContext
                     Regex [Char] (String, String, String, [Int]))
    arising from a use of ‘=~’
• In the expression:
      ("123_") =~ ("(\\d+)_" :: String) ::
        (String, String, String, [Int])
  In a pattern binding:
    (_, _, _, [sectionKey])
      = ("123_") =~ ("(\\d+)_" :: String) ::
          (String, String, String, [Int])
```

This is a simplified case, I'm looking for a solution that will provide a regex compatible solution.

Comment: Why not use `\d+` instead of `.*` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that does not seem to work either (updated the question).

Comment: What effort have you made to resolve this error? There is indeed no such instance, so of course this code doesn't work ( specify a different type such that the instance does actually exist ).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all I wouldn't use a Regex-library - because [now you got two problems](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247), haskell has a good - no great ecosystem of parsers that will do the job for you.

The solution to your problem is - I think you used the wrong regex.

```
$ stack ghci --package regex-posix --package safe
...
Prelude> :m + Safe Text.Regex.Posix
Prelude Safe Text.Regex.Posix> readMay ("123_" =~ "[0-9]+") :: Maybe Integer
Just 123
```

The downside of using regex is they are hard to understand/get right in the first place and to maintain afterwards, error prone (in my opinion) - and moreover. And when you match with it you get the matched `String`. I.e. `("123_" =~ "([0-9]+)_") :: String` will yield "123_" and not "123" thus "readMay ..."  will return a `Nothing` instead of `Just 123`.

Therefore I would recommend using a parsing library - something like [attoparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec). But as I said there are plenty of parsing alternatives if you don't like this one.

```
$ stack ghci --package attoparsec
Prelude> :set -XOverloadedStrings
Prelude> import Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8 as C8
Prelude Data.Attoparsec.Char8> :{
Prelude Data.Attoparsec.Char8| strangeNumber = do
Prelude Data.Attoparsec.Char8|   d <- decimal
Prelude Data.Attoparsec.Char8|   char '_'
Prelude Data.Attoparsec.Char8|   return d
Prelude Data.Attoparsec.Char8| :}
Prelude C8> parseOnly strangeNumber "123_" :: Either String Integer
Right 123
```

Putting this in ghci is a bit unwieldy, but in a file it is perfectly fine and maintainable - so if you want to allow for optional '_' at the beginning and/or end of the number you can write this as

`StrangeNumber.hs`

```
strangeNumber :: Parser Integer
strangeNumber = do
  skipMany (char '_')
  d <- decimal
  skipMany (char '_')
  return d
```

and using it in GHCi

```
Prelude Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8> parseOnly strangeNumber "123_"
Right 123
Prelude Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8> parseOnly strangeNumber "_123_"
Right 123
Prelude Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8> parseOnly strangeNumber "_123__"
Right 123
```